# React onMouseDown: passing event along with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an event into an handleOnMouseDown function along with two other parameters. The code I have now looks like this:
`onMouseDown={(e) => {this.handleMouseDown(e,row,col)}}`

In my handleMouseDown function I have:

```
handleMouseDown = (event,row,col) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

However, I am getting an error when I call the ".preventDefault" function. The error saying:

> TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Why is this happening?

EDIT (more context provided):
In my render function, I am generating a grid made up of nodes, each having a specific col and row number. A snippet of my code in render looks like this:

```
         {this.state.grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
              return (
                <div key={rowIdx}>
                  {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                    const {
                      row, 
                      col
                    } = node;
                    return (
                      <Node
                        key={nodeIdx}
                        col={col}
                        onMouseDown={(row,col,event) => {this.handleMouseDown(row,col,event)}}
                        row={row}></Node>
                    );
                  })}
```

In each node, I am calling the onMouseDown in my render function like this:

```
          return (
            <div onMouseDown={() => onMouseDown(row, col)}>
            </div>
          );
```

Comment: Do basic debugging: add `console.log(event);` as first line and check what it says. (code works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-field-pe7sn)

Comment: When adding the console.log(event) line, it prints out the row number. Therefore I changed my code to: `onMouseDown={(row,col,event) => {this.handleMouseDown(row,col,event)}}` and my method to

`
handleMouseDown = (row,col,event) => {
    console.log("event " + event);
    ...
}
` 
Now event is printing as "undefined"

Comment: can you give us some more context as to where youre calling this in your component?  where are `row` and `col` defined?  most of the event handler functions only take the event as the parameter

Comment: please post more of your code as the error does not match your snippet

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: I figured you were doing a map statement.  Check out my answer below, it should work for you.  Just remove the `row` and `column` from the parameters of your `onMouseDown` function, but keep them as parameters of your `handleMouseDown` callback.

Comment: I have made the following edits accordingly:
My handleMouseDown function:
`handleMouseDown = (e,row,col) => {
    e.persist();

    e.preventDefault();
}
`
My callback:
`onMouseDown={(e) => {this.handleMouseDown(e,row,col)}}`

With these edits I am getting the error "TypeError: e.persist is not a function"

Comment: If those are the only edits, you're passing the row as `e` param, then try to call `.persist()`  on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the event handlers only accept the event object as their parameter.  But that doesn't mean you can't pass other things into the `handleMouseDown` callback function.  You'd want to write it like this:

```js
handleMouseDown = (e, row, col) => {

   e.persist()
   e.preventDefault()

   console.log(e, row, col)
   // whatever you'd like to do with e, row, and col

}

// Inside your render:

const row = 'whatever'
const col = 'and stuff'

return (
  <button onMouseDown={(e) => {this.handleMouseDown(e,row,col)}}>
    This will work
  </button>
)
```

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-handlers-params-2lbbg)