# React-Events: onMouseUp not firing after onMouseEnter event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, I have a grid made up of nodes, each of which has an onMouseUp, onMouseDown, and onMouseEnter listener. I find that after I drag my mouse and move it around the grid, it does not trigger onMouseUp even after I let go of my mouse. My code can be seen below:

```
         // inside my render function
         {this.state.grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
              return (
                <div key={rowIdx}>
                  {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                    const {
                      row, 
                      col
                    } = node;
                    return (
                      <Node
                        key={nodeIdx}
                        col={col}
                        onMouseDown={(row,col) => {this.handleMouseDown(row,col)}}
                        onMouseEnter={(row, col) =>this.handleMouseEnter(row, col)}
                        onMouseUp={(row, col) =>this.handleMouseUp(row, col)}
                        row={row}></Node>
                    );
                  })}
```

My handleMouseUp function is:

```
handleMouseUp = (row,col) => {
   ...
}
```

In each node, I am referencing these callbacks by:

```
           return (
            <div
                onMouseDown={() => onMouseDown(row, col)}
                onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter(row, col)}
                onMouseUp={() => onMouseUp(row,col)}>
            </div>
          );
```

The CSS properties for each node include (not sure if this has anything to do with it):

```
    user-drag: none; 
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `onMouseUp` only fires if you *unclick* while the cursor is still in the `<div/>`. 

Try using `onDragEnd` and set `draggable='true'` in the `<div/>` and see if it works.

Edit: I would suggest moving the logic to the parent container for simplicity. You can refer to this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-painter. Some values are hard-coded but the main concept is there.

Comment: I added the no drag/select css properties because I dont want the application to think I am trying to drag the nodes to a different place when I am actually just moving my mouse over them (in my application, I want to turn the nodes I drag over into wall nodes). This was previously causing some errors and is why I added the no drag  properties. Is there a way to implement this without removing these properties?

Comment: Okay, seems like this is no spreadsheet, is it going to be like a game designer where users can paint items and walls across grids? Just wanna be sure, I don't wanna start making assumptions and give false answers.

Comment: Yup! I think my issue is close to the one listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506041/javascript-events-mouseup-not-firing-after-mousemove. However, I cant seem to get the event.preventDefault() to work properly. This is an ongoing issue in my other post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711367/react-onmousedown-passing-event-along-with-parameters. I am not sure if there are any alternative solutions. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Since this is the case, there should be a state in the container (parent component), storing the info. I would suggest adding the drag listeners and the functions in the container. I've edited my answer to elaborate on this.

Comment: Will the onMouseUp event fire once the drag event terminates? If so, why does it do so for onMouseDrag but not for onMouseEnter?

Comment: My bad, there's a typo. It should be `onMouseMove`, which fires repeatedly as the cursor moves in the container. While moving, `onMouseUp/Down` is used to determine if a "drag" is happening.

Comment: Yes, this is the code I actually have right now. My problem is that onMouseUp is not firing after onMouseMove ends.  Therefore, when I drag my mouse over the grid and then let go of the left click button on my mouse, the application still thinks mouseDown is true because the code in mouseUp is not triggered. Will the given code fix that issue?

Comment: On second thought, `window.addEventListener` would work better. Edited my answer to include a working demo.

Comment: Sweet! The windows.addEventListener approach worked. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.